# Is there a way to add an id to the div that is created when you add a marker to a google map?

Tags: google-maps

The question is pretty self-explanatory.  When a marker is added to a google map, in the DOM it looks like it is actually a div wrapped around the marker image.  It would make it a lot easier for me if those div's could be uniquely identified, e.g. I could grab individual markers on the map with getElementById() or similar. I'm using google maps v3.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of the API are you using?

Comment: Actually.. I suspect if you explained your underlying requirement that there would probably be a far better solution.

Comment: I'd like to be able to assign them dojo tooltips, amongst other things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is - you can create a custom Overlay class to include custom markup. Fortunately someone already had that idea and did it. Check out RichMarker and StyledMarker  in [Google Map Utility Libraries](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries) (at the bottom of the page) both allow you to put custom markup/css classes in marker markup.

If you just want to attach tooltips to the marker, you could also simply attach a custom property to the marker at creation (such as tooltip text or something) and add a mouseover event handler to read that property and do something with it.

Example:

```
    <html> 
    <head> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" /> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
    <title>Google Maps Markers</title> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    var map;
    //your tooltips
    msg = ['Yeah Right', 'oompa oompa','I feel good']
    var marker;
    function initialize() {
      var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.875696,-87.624207);
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: chicago,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map:map,
    position: chicago,
    title: "<h2>Sample Tooltip</h2>", //title can also be used for custom tooltips
    myCustomIndex:2 //storing index of a tooltip
    })


    //if you have multiple markers pls read about event closures http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html#EventClosures

//attach an event to the marker
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
        //you could also use the title property of the marker to hold the text of the tooltop
        showFakeTooltip(marker.title)
        //or you could show it by accessing a custom property
        showTooltip(marker.myCustomIndex);
      });
    }

    function showFakeTooltip(title) {
    $(".fakeTooltip").html(title);
    }

    function showTooltip(index) {
    alert(msg[index])
    }




    </script> 
    </head> 
    <body onload="initialize()"> 

      <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 900px;height: 600px;"></div> 
    <div class="fakeTooltip"></div>
    </body> 
    </html>
```